# Docker - Properly Mounting Host Directory in Docker Container (Windows)

Tags: node.js, docker

I am having some trouble mounting a directory on my machine into my Docker container. I would like to mount a directory containing files necessary to run a node server. So far, I have successfully been able to run and access my server in browser using the Dockerfile below:

```
# Use an ubuntu base image
FROM    ubuntu:14.04

# Install Node.js and npm (this will install the latest version for ubuntu)
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install git

# Bundle app source (note: all of my configuration files/folders are in the current directory along with the Dockerfile)

COPY . /src

Install app dependencies

#WORKDIR /src

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN bower install --allow-root
RUN npm install -g grunt
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli

#What port to expose?

EXPOSE  1234

#Run grunt on container start

CMD grunt
```

And these commands:

```
docker build -t test/test .

docker run -p 1234:1234 -d test/test
```

However, I figured that I would like the configuration files and whatnot to persist, and thought to do this by mounting the directory (with the files and Dockerfile) as a volume. I used other solutions on StackOverflow to get this command:

```
docker run -p 1234:1234 -v //c/Users/username/directory:/src -d test/test
```

My node server seems to start up fine (no errors in the log), but it takes significantly longer to do so, and when I try to access my webpage in browser I just get a blank page.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

**EDIT**: I have gotten my server to run--seems to have been a weird error in my configuration. However, it still takes a long time (around a minute or two) for my server to start when I mount a volume from my host machine. Does anyone have some insight as to why this is?

Comment: If I recall correctly, boot2docker uses VirtualBox's *shared folders* for mapping your host directory into the boot2docker VM, and from there into the Docker container. VirtualBox shared folders are [notoriously sloooow](http://mitchellh.com/comparing-filesystem-performance-in-virtual-machines). I'm not really sure if there's anything you can do about that on Windows...

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense--I will test my server on Ubuntu and see if that makes a difference. Thanks!